# Añadir la suma a un data frame

Tags: r

Tengo los siguientes datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = '
COL1 COL2      COL3
 AA      Certificado      22
 AA      Descertificado    10
 BB      Certificado      6
 BB      Descertificado  7
 CC      Certificado      1
 CC      Descertificado   2
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
 

  COL1           COL2 COL3
1   AA    Certificado   22
2   AA Descertificado   10
3   BB    Certificado    6
4   BB Descertificado    7
5   CC    Certificado    1
6   CC Descertificado    2
```

Simplemente quiero sumar la col3 agrupando por col1 y añadirlo al df

```
  COL1           COL2 COL3
   AA    Certificado   22
   AA Descertificado   10
   AA Total            32
   BB    Certificado    6
   BB Descertificado    7
   BB Total             13  
   CC    Certificado    1
   CC Descertificado    2
   CC Total             3
```

He probado con `bind_rows` combinado con `aggregate` pero no logro sacarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está muy bien tu solución, ahora si quieres un lote `dplyr` completo, puede calcular fácilmente los totales con un clásico `group_by()` y "unirlos" luego al `data.frame` original mediante `union()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

datos %>% 
  group_by(COL1) %>% 
  summarise(COL2 = 'Total',
            COL3 = sum(COL3)) %>% 
  union(datos) %>% 
  arrange(COL1, COL2)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  COL1  COL2            COL3
  <chr> <chr>          <int>
1 AA    Certificado       22
2 AA    Descertificado    10
3 AA    Total             32
4 BB    Certificado        6
5 BB    Descertificado     7
6 BB    Total             13
7 CC    Certificado        1
8 CC    Descertificado     2
9 CC    Total              3
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he resulto así, pero seguro que hay algo más directo

```
aggregate(COL3 ~ COL1, data = datos, FUN="sum") -> df2

library("plyr")
rbind.fill(datos,df2) -> df3
df3$COL2[is.na(df3$COL2)] <- "TOTAL"
df3[order(df3$COL1),]
```